# Magento 2 development environment on local server

Tags: testing, magento2, development-environment

I need to create a local development environment and struggling a little with the setup. I want to replicate my live server as close as I possibly can.

I want to install **Magento ver 2.1.8**, running **MySQL 5.6**, **PHP 7.0** with **NginX** and **Debian**.

Now, it would be more than one person which will be working on the development sites, therefore, it will have to stored on our local server.

We are working on Windows 10 Pro machines.

I had a look at tools such as **VirtualBox**, **Vagrant** and **Docker** but reading about them got me even more confused.

I had a brief look at the **LAMP** stack too. Could you recommend the best way to go for my situation?

Do I have to use these tools in combination with each other?

Do I have to install the software on each computer or on local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use this docker container: https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento2docker

It uses apache but you can change it via editing Dockerfile. Main advantage in this container is configured sshfs mounting in MacOS which works a little bit faster that default mounting, and you can work with source code as you work on local instance.